# ajax calls return error return from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I used ajax method to call the controller, fetch the data and convert it to json or list and set a jquery DataTable. With 200 records it's working fine, but when I fetch more than 1000 records, ajax method gives me: `500 internal server error`

Comment: Try setting the returned JSON size to int max

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and I have tried following changes in the **web.config** file of an application.

```
<webServices>                                                   
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />                 
</webServices>
```

I have set the maxJsonLength and this works for me. Hope this will also help you.

Comment: i tried maxJsonLength="2000000000" but it is not working